# Node JavaScript contexts sharing built-in prototypes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

When creating a new context with Node's `vm.runInNewContext`, are built-in (`Object`, `Function`, etc.) prototypes shared or not?

Documentation on `runInNewContext` says:

> Running `code` does not have access to local scope and the object `sandbox` will be used as the global object for `code`.

Is `Object.prototype` in the global scope, hence not shared?

In `node_script.cc:338-345` and `node_script.cc:403-409` I see it's *referencing* the objects, so are those objects, from `sandbox`, using the `Object.prototype` of the parent context which calls `vm.runInNewContext` and objects created in the new context using a different `Object.prototype`?

(Note: `vm` module is a maze: `vm` module -> `evals` process.binding -> `node_script.cc` source)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know the code is run in a completely new context, with different global constructors for Object, Array, etc.

```
Object.prototype.a = function() { console.log('hello'); };
({}).a(); // 'hello'
require('vm').runInNewContext('({}).a();'); // should throw
```

I don't think it would *really* be a new context if Object::a had access to variables in the original context.

This has some implications though:

```
vm.runInNewContext('[];') instanceof Array; // returns false
```

Because that array was created with a completely different constructor, the instanceof operator will be affected.

Answer (score 5):

### Conclusion

Inside a `vm.runInNewContext`, there are two `Object.prototype`s: one that is created inside the new context and one that is referencing to the parent context, via the `sandbox`. Apparently, Node has set the security tokens correctly, so contexts are allowed to access the parent's objects.

> Is `Object.prototype` in the global scope, hence not shared?

It is not in the global scope, but in the context. It's not shared.

> In node_script.cc:338-345 and node_script.cc:403-409 I see it's referencing the objects, so are those objects, from sandbox, using the Object.prototype of the parent context which calls vm.runInNewContext and objects created in the new context using a different Object.prototype?

Yes.

> When creating a new context with Node's vm.runInNewContext, are built-in (Object, Function, etc.) prototypes shared or not?

Not shared.

### The test

```
// Test

var vm = require('vm');

var parentLog = function(message) {
    process.stdout.write(message + "\n");
}

Object.prototype.test = "[parent Object.prototype.test]";

var parentObject = new String("[parent parentObject]");

var parentSandbox = {
    log: parentLog,
    testObject: parentObject,
};

var parentCode =
    "log('vm testObject: ' + testObject);" +
    "log('vm testObject.test: ' + testObject.test);" +
    "log('vm create Object.prototype.test');" +
    "Object.prototype.test = '[vm Object.prototype.test]';" +
    "log('vm Object.prototype.test: ' + Object.prototype.test);" +
    "log('vm testObject.test: ' + testObject.test);";

parentLog('pre-parent parentObject: ' + parentObject);
parentLog('pre-parent parentObject.test: ' + parentObject.test);
parentLog('pre-parent Object.prototype: ' + Object.prototype.test);

var parentScript = vm.createScript(parentCode, "<test>");
parentScript.runInNewContext(parentSandbox);

parentLog('post-parent parentObject: ' + parentObject);
parentLog('post-parent parentObject.test: ' + parentObject.test);
parentLog('post-parent Object.prototype: ' + Object.prototype.test);
```

Output:

```
pre-parent parentObject: [parent parentObject]
pre-parent parentObject.test: [parent Object.prototype.test]
pre-parent Object.prototype: [parent Object.prototype.test]
vm testObject: [parent parentObject]
vm testObject.test: [parent Object.prototype.test]
vm create Object.prototype.test
vm Object.prototype.test: [vm Object.prototype.test]
vm testObject.test: [parent Object.prototype.test]
post-parent parentObject: [parent parentObject]
post-parent parentObject.test: [parent Object.prototype.test]
post-parent Object.prototype: [parent Object.prototype.test]
```